# open doesn't return error when file is currently opened in a running process

Tags: c, file, error-handling, io

This is my code. I'm completely aware that an endless loop results when executing directly. What I did was I compiled this code and then executed twice in the linux command line via `./a.out &` twice. The first time the program executes, it runs fine and gives a decent file handle. When the first instance of the program is running in the background and I execute the second instance one minute later (via `./a.out &`), the file handle returned is the exact same. I was expecting a negative return value for the second instance to indicate the first instance is using the file.

How do I solve this issue? I don't want to use buffered file functions like fopen/fread because the file I want to make is small and must be made at the beginning of the program before anything else happens in the code.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(){
        char* pidf="/testpid.del";
        int lfp=open(pidf,O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|0x700);
        printf("File handle = %d\n",lfp);
        if (lfp ==-1){printf("Can't use PID file: %s\n",pidf);return -1;}
        while(1){
              sleep(1);
        }
        close(lfp);
}
```

Comment: Multiple processes are allowed to open the same file. If you need mutual exclusion, use file locks.

Comment: Maybe you want to use `O_EXCL`. This will cause an error if the file already exists instead of being created by this call. Just make sure that you remove the file when the process is done, so that the next instance can create it.

Comment: Also, if `0x700` is meant to be permissions for the created file, it's wrong in at least 2 ways: #1. It should be a separate argument, not ORed into the `O_*` flags. #2. `rwx------` is octal `0700` not hex `0x700`.

Comment: Ok, Barmar's idea works. turns out I used file locking along with a non-blocking parameter.